# How to install monodevelop 7?

Tags: monodevelop

Ubuntu repositories have monodevelop 5 in them.

The current version version of monodevelop is version 7.

How do I install version 7?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [MonoDevelop 7.3 as FlatPak](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/).

Flatpak is in 17.10 repositories, for previous Ubuntu releases you can use [`ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~alexlarsson/+archive/ubuntu/flatpak):

```
#sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak # for 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install flatpak 
flatpak install --from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref
```

You can it from *Applications->Programming->MonoDevelop* menu or from terminal:

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
```

Traditional APT-like method [is not recommended by program authors](http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu).